# Why do I get React error "Cannot read propery"

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the `"Cannot read property"` error when using `refs` inside a `.map` function.

What I am trying to do:

Change the background colour of specific values in the `.map`, so for example if the customer has `autorenew` on the background colour is green. If not the background colour is red.

The problem I am facing. I can make the code work on a button `onClick` function but as soon as I put it inside a `componentDidMount` I get the error `cannot read property "style" of undefined`.

My code:

```
export default class Dash extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.accordionContent = [];
  }
  accordionToggle = (value) => {
    this.accordionContent[value].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.valueToMap.map((index, value) => {
          var autoRenew = "on";
          if (autoRenew === "on") {
            this.accordionToggle(value);
          }
          return (
            <div
              ref={(ref) => (this.accordionContent[value] = ref)}
              className="mini-lower"
            >
              BACKGROUND I AM TRYING TO CHANGE
            </div>
            //other bits of code here
          );
        })}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

I can call

```
<button onClick={() => this.accordionToggle(value)} >Click</button>
```

inside the `.map` and it works fine.

Comment: how do you fill `this.accordionContent = [];`? I kindly suggest you learn how to debug/track code.

Comment: @ilkerkaran why do i need to fill it?? I am using it as a ref.

Comment: your code calls `this.accordionToggle(value)` before setting it ref. So the array still empty by then

Comment: I see... What is the way to fix this? Set the ref inside the if statement?? Code would help if you can

Comment: `this.accordionContent[value].style.backgroundColor = "red";` You are setting an object, with an index of `value` inside a `accordionContent` array to have a property `style` with a property of `backgroundColor` to be `red` but you do not have an object with such index as your array is empty. You should check if it exist in array. if it does - then set the color. if dosent - first add it to the array only then modify it. In addition, you should use a state there rather then a plain object and set it with `setState` cuz states are immutable.

Comment: @Lith Could you please post up an answer with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a really clean way to do what I was trying to achieve.

Instead of using refs i just used this below

```
className={this.state.renewalStatus[value] === 'EXPIRED' ? 'class-one' : 'class-two'}
```

Wish I had worked it out sooner!